# Is it ok to keep your macbook plugged in when battery light is green?

Tags: macbook, battery

So if your light on the macbook charger goes green (battery is charged 100%), should you unplug it or keep plugged it in?

Answer (score 2):

You can leave the charger in to run off of AC power (converted to DC first of course) from your outlet instead of draining the battery reserves. Leaving it plugged up will not hurt your macbook, but if you want to insure optimal battery life you shouldn't leave it plugged up to AC all the time.

See http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html for an overview of maintaining Apple laptop batteries.

Comment: In my experience, leaving the laptop plugged into the wall doesn't seem to hurt the battery.  A friend of mine bought a laptop almost identical to mine a few months later than I did.  I often ran off the battery, and he virtually never ran off the battery.  My battery was shot within about two years, but his lasted lasted at least twice as long as mine.