# Is it a bad idea to keep a Macbook pro always on?

Tags: mac, battery-life, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to use laptop on battery or on AC power?](https://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power)

I never turn off a macbook pro I've at home. It's always connected with the power source, but with the lid closed.

Is there a problem? Is the battery going to die slowly because of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to use laptop on battery or on AC power?](http://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power), [Is it ok to keep your macbook plugged in when battery light is green?](http://superuser.com/questions/80118/is-it-ok-to-keep-your-macbook-plugged-in-when-battery-light-is-green), ...

Comment: (It's not clear to me if you're *using* the MacBook with the lid closed. But still then: there's many duplicates here.)

Comment: @Arjan You can work with peripherals with the lid closed. Otherwise, accessories like [BookArc](http://twelvesouth.com/products/bookarc/) would be *really* pointless.

Comment: Hehe, @Daniel, I know. It's just not clear to me *if* the user is always keeping the MacBook running while connected to the A/C adapter. Closing the lid might also put it into hibernation. Anyway, given the body text and the 3 tags about battery life, and no reaction to my comments, it's a duplicate in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can, try to run the battery down every now and again. [From Apple:](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html)

*Apple does not recommend leaving your portable plugged in all the time. An ideal use would be a commuter who uses her notebook on the train, then plugs it in at the office to charge. This keeps the battery juices flowing. If on the other hand, you use a desktop computer at work, and save a notebook for infrequent travel, Apple recommends charging and discharging its battery at least once per month.*

Answer (score 6):

This debate very often pops up here. Long story short: Make sure you unplug it every once in a while (maybe weekly) and let it drain and charge. It is important to cycle the battery every once in a while for both the health and calibration of the battery. Check Apple's site for very specific Macbook battery tips [here](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html).

> For proper maintenance of a lithium-based battery, it’s important to keep the electrons in it moving occasionally. **Apple does not recommend leaving your portable plugged in all the time**. An ideal use would be a commuter who uses her notebook on the train, then plugs it in at the office to charge. This keeps the battery juices flowing.

Comment: I gave CaseyIT my vote because he posted first, but otherwise, a good answer.

Comment: @Randolph Potter - Why not upvote both? ;)  Good answers are good answers.

Comment: They point to the same link. I'm torn ... :-) Oh well, I'll relent.

Answer (score 2):

There are heat concerns - with the lid closed, there *is less space for the heat to circulate*.  The hotter many computer parts are, the more likely they will have a shortened lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the battery dying, and don't ever need battery power, <s>just remove the battery (if you have one of the newer ones), and see if the computer will remain on. Some power supplies have different circuits for charging and powering the laptop directly.</s> [Don't do this.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2332) Instead, do what others suggested and occasionally fully drain the battery (once every 2 weeks to 1 month should suffice).

I would also recommend you turn off your screen (just dim the brightness all the way) so you don't wear out (or burn in) your LCD.

Comment: Do not use MacBooks [while the battery is removed](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2332), it will decrease performance.

Comment: Fixed. I can see why this happens, but I don't agree with it, I think it's kinda dumb.